# Is sweating a necessity for the body or its normal not to sweat after the workout

Tags: sweat

I normally do 20mins on the jogger with speed of 7-8Kmph and later the dumbells of 5 kg ,dips of 4 sets with 10 each,chest press of 40lbs same 4 sets with 10 each.

After following this regime I am not feeling any sweat at all.I don't understand is it normal not to sweat or its something with the excerise being performed.

Beside me there is another person who also follows simmilar regime and sweats a lot then me.We both login,log out of the gym at the same time then why is there the difference(Some say that sweating is related to the effort in gym then am I not putting an effort)

Comment: Regarding the close votes, I don't really think it's "opinion based" that people sweat more than others. It's clinically established and at the far extremes have diagnoses. Further, it's a typical concern for anyone exercising whether from social stigma, slippery grips, or stinging eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a lot of variance in sweating ([perspiration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspiration)). Some people break into a sweat very quickly, some people not so much.

On the far ends of sweat-o-meter you have [hypohidrosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypohidrosis) in which an insufficient amount of sweat is produced. Although handy in social circles, it can become very dangerous in conditions when your body *needs* to cool down. Hypohidrosis in extreme conditions can lead to heat stroke and death.

Then there's [hyperhidrosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperhidrosis), which means you'll sweat a lot. This can also cause problems related to dehydration and skin infections.

A doctor can diagnose you with either of those, but chances are you're in the range of normal, and so is your friend, but you two just exist in different areas of "normal" (ie: not a diagnosed condition).

Also, [as your fitness increases so will the amount of sweat you produce](http://trainright.com/chris-carmichael-blog-does-sweating-more-mean-youre-more-fit/). From [Chris Carmichael](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chris_Carmichael_%28cyclist%29) (professional Olympic cycling coach, and Olympian himself):

> Improving fitness impacts the way your body works in a wide variety of
>   ways, and your sweat response to exercise changes as you become more
>   fit because you’re increasing the workload your body has to be able to
>   handle.
>   As you become more fit, you are able to work harder. You generate more
>   power ... and maintain a faster pace ...
>
> But the ability to work harder also means you have the ability
>   to generate a lot of heat in a very short period of time. You also
>   have the endurance to sustain exercise longer, meaning you have the
>   capacity to generate heat for a longer period of time. Your body has
>   to adapt to these demands in order to keep your core temperature
>   stable.